# How to analyse Orthofinder results

Tags: clustering, orthologues, clusterprofiler, orthofinder

I read this paper (*Colletotrichum shisoi sp. nov., an anthracnose pathogen of Perilla frutescens in Japan: molecular phylogenetic, morphological and genomic evidence*). We ran Orthofinder and also created an Upset plot. Unfortunately, I do not understand how they calculated the following percentages in the *"Conservation of proteins amongst Colletotrichum species"* section:

> A total of 11,914 orthogroups with two or more proteins were
> identified (Fig. 4b). Of these, 7,950 groups (74.0% proteins from C.
> shisoi, 63.0% from C. higginsianum, 78.3% from C. incanum, 74.2% from
> C. tofieldiae and 73.7% from C. graminicola) were conserved in all
> five species (Supplementary Tables S3 and S4)

How is it possible to calculate the values?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ah this is a core-genome calculation. Very interesting study indeed. Agreed its not clear but I think @CorteZero has the right idea.

Answer (score 4):

I think they simply calculate the percentage of proteins in each species that belongs to an orthogroup conserved in the five species.

There should be a tab separated text file called Orthogroups.GeneCount.tsv (at least in the Orthofinder version used in the paper). This file contains counts of the number of genes for each species in each orthogroup. You can use this file to get the total number of genes in each species associated with those 7950 orthogroups and then calculate its proportion compared to the total number of genes.

Hope this helps